# Making POST request in Tampermonkey to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, post, tampermonkey

I am using Tampermonkey to monitor a webpage for certain changes, which I am trying to record in a Google Sheet. To do this, I have a Google Apps Script, and I want to make POST requests to the Apps Script.

A snippet of my code in Tampermonkey is shown below:

```js
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "https://script.google.com/macros/s/~~scriptId~~/exec", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(data);
```

However, I am getting an error that says Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, and a net::ERR_FAILED 404 as well.

I know that `data` is correct, since it has been logged to the console. I have also deployed the Apps Script as a Web app, and setting it to execute as Me and for Anyone to have access.

I do not have much experience with JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

**Edit:** I resolved it by changing the code to

```js
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "https://script.google.com/macros/s/~~scriptId~~/exec?"+data, true);
  xhr.send();
```

Comment: I thought that your showing script works. So in this case, it is required to know your Google Apps Script side. Because when Google Apps Script occurs an error, such the error occurs. I'm worried about this. And also, in order to check your script, please provide the sample value of `data`.

Answer (score 2):

For documentation, here another solution for this case
(tested in Chrome only)

Script in Tampermonkey:

```
// @grant        GM.xmlHttpRequest

function test() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.param_0 = "abc";
    obj.param_1 = "xyz";

    sending_xml(obj);
}

function sending_xml(obj) {
    console.log("SENDING DATA");

    GM.xmlHttpRequest ({
        method:     "POST",
        url:        "https://script.google.com/macros/s/[DEPLOYMENT_ID]/exec",
        data:       JSON.stringify(obj),
        headers:    {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        onload:     function (response) {
            console.log(response); //display "ok"
        }
    });
}
```

Code.gs

```
function doPost(e) {

    var string = e.postData.getDataAsString();
    var data = JSON.parse(string);

    Logger.log(data);
    //do stuff;

    return "ok";
}

//must be deployed as WebApp, with "Access to All"
```